# Automatically mark notification read when I view the comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, global-inbox

I'm viewing a question, and someone posts a comment that notifies me.

I click on the "Show N more comments" message to show all the new comments, so I see the comment mentioned in the notification.

It would be nice if it would be automatically marked read in my inbox, so I don't have to open that up just to mark it.